# How can I interrupt channeled spells?

Tags: league-of-legends

Is it possible to stop other players from channeling their ultimates; for example, Karthus' Requiem or Fiddlesticks' Crowstorm?

Which champions have this ability?

Comment: You're confusing channeled abilities with cast time abilities. A channeled ability is something like Fiddlestick's Drain.

Comment: If I understood also Crowstorm is channeled. From the description: Fiddlesticks channels for 2 seconds until he releases the evil within him. He teleports to his targeted location with a murder of crows flocking wildly around him for 5 seconds, dealing magic damage each second to all enemy units in the area.

Comment: Cast time spells in general are often denoted as "Channeling" in LoL (See Requiem, Absolute Zero, Crowstorm), as are "true" channeling spells (See Drain, Death Lotus, Malhazar/Warwick/Urgot ults). The difference, conventionally speaking, is that channeled spells perform a constant effect as long as the channel is continued, while cast time spells only create an effect after the channel is complete.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To interrupt another player's ability (regardless of whether or not it is channeled or cast time -- it's the same ways for both) you can stun them, silence them, or kill them before the cast-time completes.

All channeled abilities can be interrupted by the channeler if you press "S" (Stop), click to move somewhere, or your champion gets stunned, silenced, knocked up, or otherwise interrupted. Knockback alone is not enough to interrupt a channeled cast, as shown [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVUpm7dsOqk&feature=related)

Comment: as a note :moving does not end fiddle's ultimate

Comment: That's because Crowstorm has a cast time, *not* a channel.

Comment: And after the cast time, the damage aura is just a buff, not an ability.

Comment: Whoa. No way! I always thought that Crowstorm's a channel. So I can run closer while casting it?

Comment: @Jonn No. Some abilities with cast times allow movement (Garen's Ult, Jax's leap strike), but others (Such As Crowstorm or Nunu's Absolute Zero) require you to be performing no other action prior to the ability being cast.

Comment: I love watching Soraka silence Fiddle as he casts his ult. So anti-climactic.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot Knock-ups and Knock-backs. Lee sin's ult and Alistar's pulverize Also stops channeling. Blitz' pull. Anything that involuntarily moves a champion will stop the channeling! Damage will not, however. Also, Be careful when using Fiddlestick's ult or Karthus ult! If you flash before the channeling finishes, the Ult WILL get interrupted! You'll lose the cooldown for your ult. So make sure you finish channeling before you flash in!

Comment: Actually, I mentioned both. However, your statement about knockbacks is not quite true. Knockback alone will not interrupt channels. Alistar's knockback also **stuns** you for the duration, which is why it interrupts. Compare to Janna's ult, which will not stun those it pushes.