# Katarina and Zhonya's Hourglass

Tags: league-of-legends

Does Zhonya's Hourglass work with Katarina's ultimate, or will her ultimate stop?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Katarina's ultimate, **Death Lotus** is a [channeled ability](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12561/how-to-stop-channeling-ultimate) (as you may notice in the cast bar that appears and counts down). Like any other channeled ability, taking any other action, such as using an item like Zhonya's Hourglass, will interrupt the channel.

Other Champions, for instance, Fiddlesticks, Kennen, or Morganna, don't need to channel to maintain their ultimate, meaning Zhonya's can be used to safely shield them for its duration.

Comment: Thank god for that. Death Lotus would be too insane if you couldn't interrupt it!