# How can an opponent stop Shen's ultimate?

Tags: league-of-legends

I enjoy watching Shen games because the global ultimate adds the excitement of unexpectedly turning the tides of a losing fight. But I'm surprised at how often [Stand United](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Shen_the_Eye_of_Twilight) completes, considering it has a 3 sec channeling time.

---

EDIT:
Emerica comments that the logistics of Shen's ultimate make it very hard to counter.

> Normally Shen's ult is used from out of combat into combat, meaning no one can get him and noone can stop him, except by killing the ally he is porting to. If it is used in combat, the  it is used just for the shield...[which] can NEVER be cancelled.

How does an opponent play to prevent Shen from completing his ult? What team strategies can be used to stop Shen's ult?

Comment: From a technical standpoint a decent amount of abilities will stop Shen's overall ult, but from a realistic standpoint it is tough to counter. Normally Shen's ult is used form out of combat into combat meaning, noone can get him and noone can stop him except killing the ally he is porting to. If it is used in combat then it is being used just for the shield (which is often very smart). The shield aspect from Shen's ult can NEVER be cancled. PS - Shen is was my favorite tank when I played LoL

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I interrupt channeled spells?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12561/how-can-i-interrupt-channeled-spells)

Comment: @Emerica. That's a great point. I guess I was wondering more about this aspect of his ult instead of just how to interrupt the channeling

Comment: Hey Timing, welcome to Arqade! Just to clarify your question, are you more interested in the strategics of playing in order to stop Shen from completing his ult rather than abilities that will interrupt the casting time?

Comment: @Timing Yeah, also important to note if you're using it as an escape mechanism you're doing it wrong lol. Shen shouldn't have any trouble getting in and out of combat.

Comment: I edited your question to reflect solicit strategies about how to stop Shen's ultimate instead of just abilities that interrupt the spell. Feel free to revert to an earlier edition if that's not what you want.

Comment: @Emerics I disagree - when I play Shen I explicitly push top past the tower so I get ganked, then I use my ultimate to bottom and push that lane. I've done this with teleport on Olaf as well ... I wouldn't underestimate the amount of time you buy by jerking your opponents from one corner of the map to another, especially if you can convince them to bring 3 or more of their teammates to gank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said by others, Shen's ultimate is a channeled spell, so any crowd control that [stops someone from channeling](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/12561/1721) will cancel the teleport aspect of Shen's spell while he's casting it. However, as the shield provided is instant, there is nothing you can do to stop the shield aspect of his ultimate.

In terms of catching Shen before he can teleport, there's lots you can do when laning against him:

1. First, pick a champion who has hard cc. If you don't then Shen is free to teleport whenever he pleases.
2. If you do have hard cc, don't make the mistake of blowing it too early! For example, Garen can only use Decisive Strike to stop Shen's ultimate, so if Garen uses it too early then Shen has 6 to 12 seconds (depending on CDR) to use his ultimate while Decisive Strike is on cooldown. This applies to stopping champions like Nunu and Katarina as well.
3. Don't let Shen hide! If he knows you can stop him he usually hides in a bush or leaves your vision to ensure his ultimate completes. This can be very hard to deal with if he Shadow Dashes far away from you. It's also hard to deal with because Shen might be baiting you away from safety so you can be ganked. Basically, be wary of Shen leaving your vision, but don't go bush-checking like a madman unless you are sure you will survive a gank from there (or you are [bush-king Garen](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GUs9nGKcx70), and decide to call his bluff).

Comment: There is one other way to stop shen from teleporting and that is to kill the target faster then the channel.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways Shen's ultimate can be interrupted. It's explained here [Interrupting Channelled Spells](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12561/how-can-i-interrupt-channeled-spells)

Comment: It would be nice if you could quote the relevant part for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Any type of Stun, Surpression or Silence will stop Shen's ult. By "Stopping Shen's Ult" it means Shen will not teleport to the ally but his ally will still get the Shield which is instant as you might already know.

For Example, Taric's Stun, Kassadin's Silence, Lee Sin Kick and more.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the standard stuns/interrupts on Shen himself, Shen's ult can also be stopped if you kill the person he is ulting unto before the channel completes. This means that you have to break through the shield (obviously), but it's a common enough thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to stop him ult, read one of the other answers. if you want to counter his ult, get globals as well. TF is probably the most viable one, Noc is good as well, Panth is ok. Teleport on any Top Laner can do a good job as well.